# How to keep an element displayed in HTML while using chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to get the Google Inbox clickable inbox setting to stay so that I can examine it:

[image]

However, as soon as I click on anything, or press Shift-Command-C to open the dev tools, the layover disappears, even if I select 'active'/'hover'/etc. from the css. How would I make this item stay visible?

Note, opening dev tools in another window or right-clicking and clicking "Inspect" doesn't work either.

Comment: Maybe open chrome dev tools on a separate window and then try?

Comment: Right click on it and inspect element

Comment: @RafaelZerbini tried both of the above -- neither worked, both made the layover disappear.

Comment: @David542 did you right clicked on the layover? that's strange, should work

Comment: @RafaelZerbini video attached: https://gyazo.com/17cfcdd0e63f778829bb4f7f20fad278. If yours works could you attach a video?

Comment: @David542 https://1drv.ms/v/s!AiPnx6asNcEmh8Bu8rxKNBthuJkvSQ

Comment: Press the pause button in devtools -> Sources panel first.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the pop-up and select `Inspect`. Drop a comment if it does not work

Comment: I think the pop-up disappears because the focus shifts from the pop up. But it should be able to point you to the html code for the pop-up